# Kotlin: Can I share data between an Activity and a Service using a Singleton object?

Tags: android, kotlin, singleton

I am using Kotlin to write an Android application. I created a singleton object using the keyword **object** to share some configuration between an Activity and its background service as follows:

```
object Configuration { var propertyMap: HashMap<String, String>() = HashMap() }
```

I initialize the Configuration object inside the service and I can use it everywhere inside the service class. However, if I try to access the singleton object inside the activity using `Configuration.propertyMap` I get an empty hashmap.

Comment: is the `Service` in the same process, what about concurrency - any threading involved? Also wouldn't it be safer to make it a `val` rather than a `var`?

Comment: Yes, it would make it safer. I found the error, the Service is running in a different process.

Answer (score 0):

To me sounds like there is a better way. Could you provide more details? 
Note also that the fact that the object is a singleton and you declare its property as val does not protect you to incur in concurrent modifications of the map. With so little context, I would consider more safer options like storing this conf. inside a database or, if you are not using a database,  SharedPreferences can help you. For example, you could store your settings as a JSON encoded string and serialize/deserialize it where you need it (this will avoid you to use serialization or Parcelable). Keep in mind that the approach you will choose depends also on the amount of data you are keeping around. If the map is large you are at risk of out of memory issues. If the two componets are on different processes you could take a look at the approach used [here](https://github.com/hamsterksu/MultiprocessPreferences).